# CSS background image exxpand as by content in html

Tags: html, css, background, cross-browser

Hi all am trying to create a info box using css by an gradient box and which must `expand` by its contents goes large and which has to support old version upto  `ie6` i can able to create box using pure `CSS and CSS3 which is not working on old browsers` so am planned to do it using background image concept but i can't able to finish it.

this is the image used as background

[Gradient rectangle box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPHIf.png)

then I sliced the images as four slice and I styled and markup ed using this four corners like

CSS

```css
.rounded-box{
    background: #fff url('../img/top-left-radius.png') no-repeat;
}
.top-right-radius{
    background: url('../img/top-right-radius.png') no-repeat top right;
}
.bottom-left-radius{
    background: url('../img/bottom-left-radius.png') no-repeat bottom left;
}
.bottom-right-radius{
    padding:20px;
    background: url('../img/bottom-right-radius.png') no-repeat bottom right;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="rounded-box">
  <div class="top-right-radius">
    <div class="bottom-left-radius">
      <div class="bottom-right-radius">
        rounded box :-)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it add the corners of the box correctly and now the problem top,bottom border and center background gradient i don't have any idea to do it please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css3pie

http://css3pie.com/

or jquery plugin

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Both solutions will allow you cross browser compatibility.